# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Keeps crashing

Tags: 14.04, kernel, crash

I installed a few updates this morning, and since then ubuntu will not stop crashing. I've attached a couple of photos which show the error I get. It's happened about four times in the last couple of hours. The first error has been different from the rest. I'll attach them both.

[First Crash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfOog.jpg)

[Second crash report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvinR.jpg)

Thanks very much in advance for your help, and if you need extra information I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: Do you see the grub menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the issue was the graphics driver. I switched to using the Nouveau display driver and haven't had the issue since

Answer (score 0):

Try Booting into recovery mode or booting from a older kernel by holding down shift going to  Advanced Options for Ubuntu and then you can choose to enter recovery mode or boot a from an older kernel.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give that a go this afternoon. If that works is it a case of pinning that kernel or something? I did read something about that, or reverting to that kernel and marking the current one to not update or something?

Comment: Unfortunately, still having issues. I went all the way back to kernel v 11 and that stopped the crashing issue, although now it just freezes all the time!